# openstack: verify routing and communicationin chain network topology

Tags: networking, router, ping, openstack

I have built a chain topology in OpenStack Network Topology. In order to verify, if the node could communicate each other, I have tried to use the VM to ping the addresses of them. A simple example is 3 nodes and 2 edges connection likes below:

O1--X--O2--X--O3

O1, O2, O3 are networks, X means router.

By using the VM I could verify O1 and O2, O2 and O3 are communicated. (ping the ip addresses for each other)

But I could not verify the communication between O1 and O3, theoretically they should be connected for each other.

I do not know how to verify them and where it might be the problem. I am looking for your help to explain and tell me how to verify O1 and O3 could ping each other.

Thanks for you help.